# How to compare two columns of matrix in r and output the column name in a new vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

**I have a matrix with 2 columns and 1000 rows**

```
         first   second
1        0.96     1.34
2        0.67     1.22
3        1        0.87
..
1000      12      11
```

I want to compare the two columns for every row of matrix and output the value in a new vector with values either "first" or "second"

My output should be

```
second second first .... first
```

I want to do this in R

What I have tried so far in R

```
if(data[2] > data[1]) "second" else "first"
```

This is returning a vector of only 1 value. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the vectorized version of if/else.  The matrix version:

```
ifelse(data[,2] > data[,1], "second", "first")
```

Comment: length(ifelse(data[[2]] > data[[1]], "second", "first")) returns 1. Is there any syntax I should change?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, Gregor!  fixed!

Comment: Thanks @Gregor and Melissa, upvoting it

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Melissa's answer. This is a little less clear, but a little more efficient than `ifelse`.

```
colnames(data)[(data[, 2] > data[, 1]) + 1L]
```

The comparison will output `TRUE` or `FALSE` (equivalent to `1` or `0`). When we add 1 it becomes 2 or 1. We can use that to index the column names.